# Pylint error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, false-positive

I'm getting many pylint false positive and it seems so ordinary that I cannot imagine it hasn't been solved yet :-/

The following code generates a false positive in pylint since it does not recognise keyword arguments correctly:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *t, x=None):
        if x==1:  # E0601, using variable 'x' before assignment
            x=2
        print(x)

A(x=1)
```

This is usually due to pylint misinterpreting keyword arguments after a `*`.
Do you know if pylint is still active, where to report it, or how to find if someone has patched this yet? I cannot find something helpful with google :(
Maybe by chance, someone knows a patch as it seems to ordinary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't actually valid Python (at least in 2.x). Specific keyword arguments must go before `*args` and `**kwargs`. You'll see an error if you try to paste this into the Python shell. It should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, x=None, *t):
```

Comment: `def __init__(self, *t, x=None)` is perfectly valid in Python 3.  `x` is known as a keyword-only argument.  See [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Comment: Oh, does that mean I'm using Python 3 specials?

Comment: @MariusGedminas I wasn't aware of that. Edited to clarify that my answer applies to 2.x only.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know if pylint is still active, where to report it, or how to find if someone has patched this yet?

I lurk in the [mailing list for Pylint](http://lists.logilab.org/mailman/listinfo/python-projects) and other logilab projects.  It's not very active, but it's not dead yet.

Pylint's bug tracker can be found at http://www.logilab.org/857

There's also an IRC channel mentioned on [Pylint's project page](http://www.logilab.org/857): #pylint on FreeNode.

Comment: Oh, so what's correct the way to report it and is there any chance of this getting fixed any time? :)

Answer (score 1):

Pylint is not dead at all! The best way to report pb is to file ticket on http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint or the python-projects@logilab.org mailing-list. IRC is fine but is not the preferred way.

Python 3 support is slowly moving on as we don't use it that much yet at Logilab. But as in other open source project, patches are warmly welcome.